# Webpage not refreshed after I added or deleted item (Node.js/Express/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I tried to build a to-do-list website with MongoDB, but I found my website is not refreshed after I added or deleted the item (check the checkbox to remove the item). Below is my JavaScript code, can someone tell me what I missed please? Thank you.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();

let checkedItemId = "";
let deletedListName = "";

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');  // Use template engine 

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));  // Mounts the specified function or function at the specified path.

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todolistDB");

const itemsSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({  // Set the collection schema
  name: String
}); 

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);   // Create instant that based on the above schema

const item1 = new Item({
  name: "Brush teeth"  
});

const item2 = new Item({
  name: "Breakfast"  
});

const item3 = new Item({
  name: "Work"  
});

const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];

const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]  
};
 
const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);

async function getItems(){
  const Items = await Item.find({});  // {} Means find all documents
  return Items;
}

async function deleteCheckedItems(){
  const CheckedItems = await Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId);
  return CheckedItems;
}

async function getListName(inputName) {
  const foundList = await List.findOne({name: inputName});
  return foundList;
}

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  getItems().then(function(foundItems){  
    if (foundItems.length === 0) {
      Item.insertMany(defaultItems);
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: foundItems});
    }    
  }); 
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listName = req.body.list;

  const item = new Item({
    name: itemName
  }); 
  
  if (listName === "Today"){  // "Today" is the default homepage in this case
    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  } else {
    getListName(listName).then(function(foundList){
      foundList.items.push(item);  // Adds new elements to the end of an array, and returns the new length
      foundList.save();

      res.redirect("/" + listName);
    })
  }  
});

app.post("/delete", function(req,res){
  checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
  deletedListName = req.body.list;
  
  deleteCheckedItems().then(function(err){
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Successfully deleted checked items");    
    }
  });

  console.log(deletedListName);
  
});

app.get("/:customListName", function(req, res){
  const customListName = req.params.customListName;
  
  getListName(customListName).then(function(recListName) {
     
    if (!recListName) {
      // Create new list
      const list = new List({
        name: customListName,
        items: defaultItems
      });

      list.save();

      res.redirect("/" + customListName);
    } else {
      // Show an existing list
      res.render("list", {listTitle: recListName.name, newListItems: recListName.items});
    } 
  });  
  
});
```

Since the tutorial used the old mongoose version, I searched what I can do for the latest version, but it didn't work like I expected which is I add or remove item and webpage will be refreshed automatically.

/* Additional information */

My list.ejs code

```
<%- include("header") -%>

  <div class="box" id="heading">
    <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
      <form action="/delete" method="post">
        <div class="item">
          <input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>">
          <p><%= item.name %></p>
        </div>

      </form>
    <% }) %>

      <form class="item" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item" autocomplete="off">
        <button type="submit" name="list" value="<%= listTitle %>">+</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Here is the screenshots of my webpage which is http://localhost:3000/.
[1. Initial Home Page has 4 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNOd6.png)

[2. Once I check the checkbox on the last item, it crosses out the item which is designed by the JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Ya2.png)

[3. Once I refreshed the webpage, then it shows correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4d14.png)

When I go to http://localhost:3000/Home page and delete the item and refresh, nothing happen and item is still on the webpage and MongoDB database. Any tips is welcomed.

Comment: Can you show us what you got on the frontend? There is nothing wrong with the backend code, I suspect it's your logic that is faulty.

Comment: Sure, please see my additional information under /* Additional information */ session on my original post. Thank you.

Comment: I was asking for the code of the frontend app not screenshots of the ui

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding, please see the codes of the ejs page on my original post above. Thanks.